# How can I prevent a package from loading into a notebook run from Workbench?

Tags: packages, workbench

I have a Workbench project in which I have created two packages: `PackageA.m` and `PackageB.m`.  In the same project, there is a notebook called `Test.nb`.

When I right-click `Test.nb` in the navigator and select `Run As -> Mathematica`, I find that all of the symbols in the two packages are loaded even though I have not actually executed

```
(* These lines have not been executed! *)
<<"PackageA`";
<<"PackageB`";
```

For instance, when I run

```
(* DemoSum is a function defined in PackageA *)
DemoSum[2, 3]
```

I get the answer `5`.

Is there a way to prevent all the packages from loading automatically when I right-click a notebook and select "Run As -> Mathematica"?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to do that rather than simply opening your notebook outside the Workbench ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks It is a pretty big code base, and there is a lot of code that I would have to copy over if I were to open the notebook outside of Workbench.  (But I am headed in that direction since I am refactoring everything.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File Loading in Workbench is controlled by couple of properties.

First there's [Execution Build Command](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/initialization.html) that is part of [project properties](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/reference/projectresources.html).
If "Execution Build Command" is set it is evaluated when you start Mathematica session using "Run As -> Mathematica". If during such session you save changes to any source file, "Execution Build Command" is evaluated again.

If there's no "Execution Build Command" in a project, then [automatic file loading](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/loadingfiles.html) occurs. Whether source files, will be loaded when working in particular notebook is controlled by [notebook properties](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/reference/notebookprops.html). Which source files will be loaded (if any) is controlled by [source file properties](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/reference/fileprops.html).

So you have three options.

1. Disable automatic package loading completely, in a project, by setting "Execution Build Command" to something that doesn't load packages e.g. `None`.
2. Disable automatic package loading for particular notebook, by removing "Execution Build Command" and choosing "No" in "Load all source files on startup" section of notebook properties.
3. Disable automatic loading of specific packages, by removing "Execution Build Command" and choosing "No" in "Automatic load on startup:" section of source file properties.